# This script is no longer working on the website. Are there any Syntax errors or other issues in the code that i'm not seeing?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am having trouble fixing this script from the website. I didn't make it but for some reason, it stopped working when I tried to add a new product. Can someone help Identify the Error and a fix for it?

```
<script>
    window.AustinProducts = {
        "Digital Cameras":{
            "Canon": [{
                name: "Canon EOS R6 Camera Body Only",
                daily_price: 85.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801186/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EOS R6 Camera with 24-105mm f/4L Lens",
                daily_price: 125.00,
                deposit: 340,
                link: "/R801172/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EOS 1DX II DSLR Camera Body",
                daily_price: 112.50,
                deposit: 650,
                link: "/R801177/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EOS 5D Mark IV DSLR Camera Body",
                daily_price: 95.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801024/",
                field_name: ""
            }
        ],
            "Nikon": [{
                name: "Nikon Z 9 Camera Body",
                daily_price: 150.00,
                deposit: 550,
                link: "/R801181/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon Z 6II Camera with 24-70mm Lens",
                daily_price: 95.00,
                deposit: 260,
                link: "/R801165/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon Z 7II Camera with 24-70mm f/4 Lens",
                daily_price: 95.00,
                deposit: 360,
                link: "/R801169/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon D750 DSLR Camera Body",
                daily_price: 95.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800979/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon D850 DSLR Camera Body",
                daily_price: 140.00,
                deposit: 280,
                link: "/R801011/",
                field_name: ""
            }
        ],
            "Sony": [{
                name: "Sony a9 II Camera Body",
                daily_price: 95.00,
                deposit: 450,
                link: "/R8010362/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony A7R IV Camera Body",
                daily_price: 95.00,
                deposit: 350,
                link: "/R801110/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony A7 IV Camera Body",
                daily_price: 95.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801182/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony a7S III Camera Body",
                daily_price: 85.00,
                deposit: 350,
                link: "/R801176/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony a7 III Camera Body",
                daily_price: 85.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801080/",
                field_name: ""
            }     
        ],
    },
        "Lenses": {
            "Canon": [{
                name: "Canon RF 15-35mm f/2.8L IS USM Lens",
                daily_price: 35.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801155/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon RF 24-70mm f/2.8L IS Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801120/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon RF 70-200mm f/2.8L Lens",
                daily_price: 45.00,
                deposit: 260,
                link: "/R801157/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon RF 70-200mm f/4L IS Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801185/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon RF 35mm f/1.8 IS Macro STM Lens",
                daily_price: 25.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801117/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon RF 50mm f/1.2L USM Lens",
                daily_price: 40.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801162/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon RF 85mm f/1.2L Lens",
                daily_price: 40.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801173/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF-EOS R Mount Adapter",
                daily_price: 10.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801175/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon Extender EF 1.4X II",
                daily_price: 10.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/r800594/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF-S 10-22mm f/3.5-4.5 USM Lens",
                daily_price: 20.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800649/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Rokinon 14mm f/3.1 Cine Lens - Canon EF",
                daily_price: 20.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800934/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF 16-35mm f/2.8L II USM Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800669/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon TS-E 24mm f/3.5L II Tilt-Shift Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800438/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF 24-70mm f/2.8L II USM Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800930/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF 24-105mm f/4L IS II USM Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800527/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF 35mm f/1.4L II USM Lens",
                daily_price: 25.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800525/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sigma 35mm f/1.4 AF DG Art Lens - Canon EF",
                daily_price: 25.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R8001005/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF 50mm f/1.2L USM Lens",
                daily_price: 40.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800590/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF 50mm f/1.4 USM Lens",
                daily_price: 15.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800472/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sigma 50mm f/1.4 DG HSM Art Lens - Canon EF",
                daily_price: 25.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801009/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF 70-200mm f/2.8L IS II USM Lens",
                daily_price: 45.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "R800650/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF 85mm f/1.2L II USM Lens",
                daily_price: 40.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800579/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro IS USM Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800591/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sigma 150-600mm f/5-6.3 Lens - Canon EF",
                daily_price: 40.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800999/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF 300mm f/4L IS USM Lens",
                daily_price: 25.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800432/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EF 400mm f/2.8L II Lens",
                daily_price: 65.00,
                deposit: 1200,
                link: "/R800589/",
                field_name: ""
            }
        ],
            "Nikon": [{
                name: "Nikon Z 85mm f/1.8 S Lens",
                daily_price: 25.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801194/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon Z 24-70mm f/2.8 S Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801123/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon Z 70-200mm f/2.8 S Lens",
                daily_price: 45.00,
                deposit: 270,
                link: "/R801164/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon AF-S 14-24mm f/2.8G ED Lens",
                daily_price: 40.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800583/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon AF-S 17-55mm f/2.8G IF-ED DX Lens",
                daily_price: 25.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800674/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon PC-E 24mm f/3.5D ED Tilt-Shift Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800654/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon AF-S 24-70mm f/2.8G Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800520/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon AF-S 50mm f/1.4G Lens",
                daily_price: 15.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800580/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon AF-S NIKKOR 70-200mm f/2.8G ED VR II Lens",
                daily_price: 45.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800586/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon AF-S 85mm f/1.4G Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800664/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon AF-S 105mm f/2.8 Macro VR Lens",
                daily_price: 25.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800931/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon AF-S NIKKOR 200-500mm f/5.6E ED VR Lens",
                daily_price: 50.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801101/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon AF-S 500mm f/4 E FL VR Lens",
                daily_price: 65.00,
                deposit: 1030,
                link: "/R801174/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Nikon 1.4x AF-I Teleconverter",
                daily_price: 10.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800595/",
                field_name: ""
            }
        ],
            "Sony": [{
                name: "Sony FE 12-24mm f/4 G Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801112/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony FE 16-35mm f/2.8 GM Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801081/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony FE 24-70mm f/2.8 GM Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801076/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony FE 24-70mm f/4 Lens",
                daily_price: 25.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801054/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony Distagon T* FE 35mm f/1.4 ZA Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801031/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony Planar T* FE 50mm f/1.4 ZA Lens",
                daily_price: 30.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801103/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony FE 70-200mm f/2.8 GM OSS Lens",
                daily_price: 45.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801084/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony FE 85mm f/1.4 GM Lens",
                daily_price: 35.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801030/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony FE 90mm f/2.8 Macro GM Lens",
                daily_price: 35.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801102/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony FE 100-400mm f/4.5-5.6 GM OSS Lens",
                daily_price: 40.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801069/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony FE 200-600mm f/5.6-6.3 G OSS Lens",
                daily_price: 50.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801161/",
                field_name: ""
            }
        ],
    },
        "Video": {
            "Canon": [{
                name: "Canon EOS R5C Camera Body",
                daily_price: 95.00,
                deposit: 480,
                link: "/R801195/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EOS C70 Cinema Camera Body",
                daily_price: 150.00,
                deposit: 550,
                link: "/R801139/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Canon EOS C300 Mark II Cinema Camera Body",
                daily_price: 175.00,
                deposit: 750,
                link: "/R801167/",
                field_name: ""
            }
        ],
            "Sony": [{
                name: "Sony FX3 Full-Frame Cinema Camera Body",
                daily_price: 115.00,
                deposit: 390,
                link: "/R801168/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony HXR-NX5U NXCAM Professional Camcorder",
                daily_price: 125.00,
                deposit: 400,
                link: "/R800950/",
                field_name: ""
            }
        ]
    },
    "Camera Support": {
        "Tripods": [{
                name: "Manfrotto 055XB Tripod with 496RC2 Ball Head",
                daily_price: 15.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800606/",
                field_name: ""
            }
        ],
    },
    "Studio & Lighting": {
        "Flashes": [{
                name: "Nikon SB-910 AF Speedlight",
                daily_price: 25.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800965/",
                field_name: ""
            },{
                name: "Sony HVL-F60RM Wireless Radio Flash",
                daily_price: 25.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R801085/",
                field_name: ""
            }
        ],
        "Strobe Lighting": [{
                name: "Profoto B10X Plus OCF Flash Duo Kit",
                daily_price: 95.00,
                deposit: 470,
                link: "/R801170/",
                field_name: ""
            }
        ],
    },
    "Projectors": {
        "Projectors": [{
                name: "Philips Screeneo HDP1690 Home Theater Projector",
                daily_price: 50.00,
                deposit: 250,
                link: "/R800600/",
                field_name: ""
            }
        ],
    },
};
        var pid = '{{page.id}}';
    if(pid == 10192){
     window.RentalProducts = window.AustinProducts;
    }
</script>
```

I fixed it last time by taking out an extra {} that was left over. I tried checking the syntax and it looked like it was correct. I know this fix has to be easy I am just a bit of a noob at web dev.

Comment: The script looks ok but you have `{{page.id}}` in there which looks like something from a templating language. You should check what that actually contains

Answer (score 0):

You have trailing commas, which JSON does not support (sadly)

```
{
   "Digital Cameras":{
      "Canon":[
         {
            "name":"Canon EOS R6 Camera Body Only",
            "daily_price":85.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801186/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EOS R6 Camera with 24-105mm f/4L Lens",
            "daily_price":125.00,
            "deposit":340,
            "link":"/R801172/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EOS 1DX II DSLR Camera Body",
            "daily_price":112.50,
            "deposit":650,
            "link":"/R801177/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EOS 5D Mark IV DSLR Camera Body",
            "daily_price":95.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801024/",
            "field_name":""
         }
      ],
      "Nikon":[
         {
            "name":"Nikon Z 9 Camera Body",
            "daily_price":150.00,
            "deposit":550,
            "link":"/R801181/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon Z 6II Camera with 24-70mm Lens",
            "daily_price":95.00,
            "deposit":260,
            "link":"/R801165/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon Z 7II Camera with 24-70mm f/4 Lens",
            "daily_price":95.00,
            "deposit":360,
            "link":"/R801169/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon D750 DSLR Camera Body",
            "daily_price":95.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800979/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon D850 DSLR Camera Body",
            "daily_price":140.00,
            "deposit":280,
            "link":"/R801011/",
            "field_name":""
         }
      ],
      "Sony":[
         {
            "name":"Sony a9 II Camera Body",
            "daily_price":95.00,
            "deposit":450,
            "link":"/R8010362/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony A7R IV Camera Body",
            "daily_price":95.00,
            "deposit":350,
            "link":"/R801110/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony A7 IV Camera Body",
            "daily_price":95.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801182/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony a7S III Camera Body",
            "daily_price":85.00,
            "deposit":350,
            "link":"/R801176/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony a7 III Camera Body",
            "daily_price":85.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801080/",
            "field_name":""
         }
      ]
   },
   "Lenses":{
      "Canon":[
         {
            "name":"Canon RF 15-35mm f/2.8L IS USM Lens",
            "daily_price":35.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801155/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon RF 24-70mm f/2.8L IS Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801120/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon RF 70-200mm f/2.8L Lens",
            "daily_price":45.00,
            "deposit":260,
            "link":"/R801157/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon RF 70-200mm f/4L IS Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801185/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon RF 35mm f/1.8 IS Macro STM Lens",
            "daily_price":25.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801117/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon RF 50mm f/1.2L USM Lens",
            "daily_price":40.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801162/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon RF 85mm f/1.2L Lens",
            "daily_price":40.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801173/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF-EOS R Mount Adapter",
            "daily_price":10.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801175/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon Extender EF 1.4X II",
            "daily_price":10.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/r800594/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF-S 10-22mm f/3.5-4.5 USM Lens",
            "daily_price":20.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800649/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Rokinon 14mm f/3.1 Cine Lens - Canon EF",
            "daily_price":20.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800934/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF 16-35mm f/2.8L II USM Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800669/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon TS-E 24mm f/3.5L II Tilt-Shift Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800438/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF 24-70mm f/2.8L II USM Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800930/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF 24-105mm f/4L IS II USM Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800527/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF 35mm f/1.4L II USM Lens",
            "daily_price":25.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800525/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sigma 35mm f/1.4 AF DG Art Lens - Canon EF",
            "daily_price":25.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R8001005/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF 50mm f/1.2L USM Lens",
            "daily_price":40.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800590/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF 50mm f/1.4 USM Lens",
            "daily_price":15.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800472/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sigma 50mm f/1.4 DG HSM Art Lens - Canon EF",
            "daily_price":25.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801009/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF 70-200mm f/2.8L IS II USM Lens",
            "daily_price":45.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"R800650/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF 85mm f/1.2L II USM Lens",
            "daily_price":40.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800579/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro IS USM Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800591/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sigma 150-600mm f/5-6.3 Lens - Canon EF",
            "daily_price":40.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800999/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF 300mm f/4L IS USM Lens",
            "daily_price":25.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800432/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EF 400mm f/2.8L II Lens",
            "daily_price":65.00,
            "deposit":1200,
            "link":"/R800589/",
            "field_name":""
         }
      ],
      "Nikon":[
         {
            "name":"Nikon Z 85mm f/1.8 S Lens",
            "daily_price":25.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801194/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon Z 24-70mm f/2.8 S Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801123/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon Z 70-200mm f/2.8 S Lens",
            "daily_price":45.00,
            "deposit":270,
            "link":"/R801164/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon AF-S 14-24mm f/2.8G ED Lens",
            "daily_price":40.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800583/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon AF-S 17-55mm f/2.8G IF-ED DX Lens",
            "daily_price":25.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800674/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon PC-E 24mm f/3.5D ED Tilt-Shift Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800654/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon AF-S 24-70mm f/2.8G Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800520/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon AF-S 50mm f/1.4G Lens",
            "daily_price":15.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800580/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon AF-S NIKKOR 70-200mm f/2.8G ED VR II Lens",
            "daily_price":45.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800586/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon AF-S 85mm f/1.4G Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800664/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon AF-S 105mm f/2.8 Macro VR Lens",
            "daily_price":25.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800931/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon AF-S NIKKOR 200-500mm f/5.6E ED VR Lens",
            "daily_price":50.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801101/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon AF-S 500mm f/4 E FL VR Lens",
            "daily_price":65.00,
            "deposit":1030,
            "link":"/R801174/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Nikon 1.4x AF-I Teleconverter",
            "daily_price":10.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800595/",
            "field_name":""
         }
      ],
      "Sony":[
         {
            "name":"Sony FE 12-24mm f/4 G Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801112/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony FE 16-35mm f/2.8 GM Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801081/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony FE 24-70mm f/2.8 GM Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801076/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony FE 24-70mm f/4 Lens",
            "daily_price":25.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801054/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony Distagon T* FE 35mm f/1.4 ZA Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801031/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony Planar T* FE 50mm f/1.4 ZA Lens",
            "daily_price":30.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801103/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony FE 70-200mm f/2.8 GM OSS Lens",
            "daily_price":45.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801084/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony FE 85mm f/1.4 GM Lens",
            "daily_price":35.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801030/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony FE 90mm f/2.8 Macro GM Lens",
            "daily_price":35.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801102/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony FE 100-400mm f/4.5-5.6 GM OSS Lens",
            "daily_price":40.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801069/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony FE 200-600mm f/5.6-6.3 G OSS Lens",
            "daily_price":50.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801161/",
            "field_name":""
         }
      ]
   },
   "Video":{
      "Canon":[
         {
            "name":"Canon EOS R5C Camera Body",
            "daily_price":95.00,
            "deposit":480,
            "link":"/R801195/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EOS C70 Cinema Camera Body",
            "daily_price":150.00,
            "deposit":550,
            "link":"/R801139/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Canon EOS C300 Mark II Cinema Camera Body",
            "daily_price":175.00,
            "deposit":750,
            "link":"/R801167/",
            "field_name":""
         }
      ],
      "Sony":[
         {
            "name":"Sony FX3 Full-Frame Cinema Camera Body",
            "daily_price":115.00,
            "deposit":390,
            "link":"/R801168/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony HXR-NX5U NXCAM Professional Camcorder",
            "daily_price":125.00,
            "deposit":400,
            "link":"/R800950/",
            "field_name":""
         }
      ]
   },
   "Camera Support":{
      "Tripods":[
         {
            "name":"Manfrotto 055XB Tripod with 496RC2 Ball Head",
            "daily_price":15.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800606/",
            "field_name":""
         }
      ]
   },
   "Studio & Lighting":{
      "Flashes":[
         {
            "name":"Nikon SB-910 AF Speedlight",
            "daily_price":25.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800965/",
            "field_name":""
         },
         {
            "name":"Sony HVL-F60RM Wireless Radio Flash",
            "daily_price":25.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R801085/",
            "field_name":""
         }
      ],
      "Strobe Lighting":[
         {
            "name":"Profoto B10X Plus OCF Flash Duo Kit",
            "daily_price":95.00,
            "deposit":470,
            "link":"/R801170/",
            "field_name":""
         }
      ]
   },
   "Projectors":{
      "Projectors":[
         {
            "name":"Philips Screeneo HDP1690 Home Theater Projector",
            "daily_price":50.00,
            "deposit":250,
            "link":"/R800600/",
            "field_name":""
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This is your massive object, with the trailing commas removed.